# Decomposing a polynomial vanishing on the points of an algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}^3$ be an algebraic curve that contains no lines parallel to $z$-axis (we fix coordinates $x,y,z$). Suppose then that $h(x,y,z)=g_0(x,y)z^n+\ldots+g_n(x,y)$ is the irreducible polynomial of the smallest possible degree with respect to $z$, that lies in $I(X)$ (the ideal, generated by all polynomials, vanishing on $X$). Prove that if $f \in I(X)$ and the degree of $f$ with respect to $z$ is equal to $m$ then $f\cdot g_0^m=h\cdot U+ v(x,y)$.

I wish to argue that since $h$ is the polynomial of the smallest possible degree with respect to $z$, we can use it as one of the generators of $I(X)$ alongside with some other polynomials, however I cannot see, why is it important to multiply by $g_0^m$ and thus I am not sure of this line of reasoning.

Could you please help me out, any aid would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hint. Notice that if $m<n$, then $f=v(x,y)$. So, we may assume $m\geq n$. Let $f=p(x,y)z^m+\cdots$. Then $fg_0-pz^{m-n}h$ has $z$-degree strictly less than $m$ and use induction.